# CorePlot using Rubymotion

Tags: core-plot, rubymotion

I'm playing around with CorePlot using rubymotion.

Can anyone help me translate this objective c method call to rubymotion syntax?

```
overlayGradient = [overlayGradient addColorStop:[[CPTColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0] atPosition:0.9];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is in RubyMotion syntax:

```
overlayGradient = overlayGradient.addColorStop(CPTColor.blackColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.0), atPosition:0.9)
```

Comment: Thanks @vacawama, it was the comma that was throwing me off.